# Spring MVC (6.0.2) - dispatcher servlet not working (404 error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

I'm new in Spring but i've already made simple spring-mvc projects in spring 5, now i decided to choose new 6 version and do everything the same way, but it does not work.

SpringConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.example")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        // IT DOES NOT GO HERE!!!!
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return templateResolver;
    }
```

MySpringMVCDispatcherServletInitializer.java:

```
public class MySpringMVCDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }

}
```

I can see that somehow "public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry)" is not getting called and as far as I understand it is the problem why no controller is working.
What should I do?

Comment: When using Spring 6, you need a JakartaEE server. If you are deploying to Tomcat 9 nothing will work you need at least Tomcat 10.